# Prove that $H(x^2)/H(x)$ increases where $H(x)$ is the harmonic number

Tags: derivatives, harmonic-numbers

This question came from my misunderstanding of this question
[Prove $\displaystyle\frac{H(x^2)}{H(x)}$ increases.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4613282/prove-displaystyle-frachx2hx-increases) where H(x) is an entropy function. I have read H(x) as the harmonic number and found that the claim holds as well.

Define $f(x) = \frac{H(x^2)}{H(x)}$

where $H(x)$ is the harmonic number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) defined for positive integers $x=n$ as $H(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$ and for real $x$ as $H(x) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-t^x}{1-t}\;dt$

My first attempts are:

Plotting $f(x)$ indicates that the claim holds.

Now we consider the two limiting cases $x \to 0$ and $x \to \infty $

For $x \to 0$ we have $H(x) = \sum_{k\ge 2}(-1)^k x^{k-1}\zeta(k) \simeq x \; \zeta(2)$ and hence $f(x) \simeq x $ which is obviously increasing.

For $x \to \infty $ we have the well known approximation $H(x) \simeq  \gamma + \log(x)$ where Euler's $\gamma$ appears. This  leads to $f(x) \simeq \frac{\gamma + \log(x^2)}{\gamma + \log(x)}=\frac{\gamma + 2\log(x)}{\gamma + \log(x)}= 1 + \frac{\log(x)}{\gamma + \log(x)}$. The drivative is $f'(x) \simeq \frac{\gamma }{x (\log (x)+\gamma )^2}$ which is positive showing that $f(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: Interesting genesis of an interesting problem !

Comment: Mathematica indicates $\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\frac{H_{x^2}}{H_x}=2$.

Comment: @ Steven Clark. This limit follows directly from the asymptotic expansion given in the OP.