# Positivity of a function involving harmonic numbers

Tags: functions, harmonic-numbers

Let

$$\begin{align}f(x) = 2 x H(x) \left(\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-H\left(x^2,2\right)\right)\\
-H\left(x^2\right) \left(\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-H(x,2)\right)\end{align}\tag{1}$$

Here $H$ are hamonic numbers, c.f.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Explicitly, for integer positive $k$, $H(k,m) =H_{k,m} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^m}$ is the generalized harmonic number and, by definition, $H(k) = H(k,1)$. For real $x\gt0$ we have the integral representations $H(x) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-t^x)}{1-t}\;dt$ and $H(x,2) =\frac{\pi^2}{6} - \int_{0}^{1}\log(\frac{1}{t})\frac{t^x}{1-t}\;dt$.

In this question [Prove that $H(x^2)/H(x)$ increases where $H(x)$ is the harmonic number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4616828/198592) I have shown that $f(x)$ is positive for $x \gt 0$, asymptotically for both small $x$ and large $x$.

Now I want to prove positivity for any $x \gt 0$. I tried to employ inequalities like

$$2 x H(x)-H\left(x^2\right) \gt 0\tag{2a}$$

$$\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-H\left(z,2\right) \gt 0 \text{, }z>0\tag{2b}$$

For $0<x<1$ we have

$$\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-H\left(x^2,2\right)>\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-H(x,2)\tag{3}$$

so that, by $(2)$ and $(3)$,

$$\begin{align}& f(0 \lt x \lt 1) \\
& > \left(2 x H(x) -H\left(x^2\right)\right) \left(\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-H(x,2)\right)\\
& >0\end{align}\tag{4}$$

So we are left with the region $x\gt 1$.

Even though it seems to be a simple task I am moving in circles, and I kindly ask for your help.

Comment: Could you define precisely $H(x)$ and $H(x,2)$? I have a good guess what they are but still.

Comment: @ Gary Thank you for the request. I have added the definitions.

Comment: What you can try is to write $$
f(x) = 2x(\psi (x + 1) + \gamma )\zeta (2,x^2  + 1) - (\psi (x^2  + 1) + \gamma )\zeta (2,x + 1)
$$ and use the known large-$x$ asymptotics of the special functions up to a certain number of terms. The error in each expansion is bounded by the first omitted term and has the same sign for all $x>0$.